# Consumption of 2 Legged OAuth authentication (or) Consumer key OAuth webservices using Restkit

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, oauth, restkit

I have configured 2 legged OAuth services in my web as in accordance with this guide:
http://drupal.org/node/1827698

I am pretty sure that the configuration is all proper, for when I trigger the webservice using the base URL + service endpoint through the web browser, the browser returns me this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<result>The request must be signed</result>
```

Which does kind of suggest that it is an authentication error. I suppose.

Now I have plans of using Restkit in my iPhone project. I followed this guide to write down a simple 2 legged OAuth webservice request:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/OAuth-Support-on-RestKit

And this is my code:

```
    NSString *urlResource = @"";
    urlResource = @"/service_endpoint/node";
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:@"http://mydomain.com/"];
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
    objectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerKey = @"proper_consumer_key";
    objectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerSecret = @"proper_consumer_secret";
    objectManager.client.OAuth1AccessToken = nil;
    objectManager.client.OAuth1AccessTokenSecret = nil;
    objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth1;
#define USE_GET_REQUEST 0
#if USE_GET_REQUEST
    [objectManager.client get:urlResource delegate:self];
#else
    NSDictionary *theParams = nil;
    NSString *timeStamp = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:(NSTimeInterval)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] stringValue];
    theParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.0", @"oauth_version", @"HMAC-SHA1", @"oauth_signature_method", timeStamp, @"oauth_timestamp", nil];
    [objectManager.client post:urlResource
                        params:theParams
                      delegate:self];
#endif
```

I tried with GET request earlier as indicated in the [post](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/OAuth-Support-on-RestKit). I get an empty body without any data and somewhere Restkit logs this, which indicates authorization problem:

> 2012-11-06 19:27:46.887 MyProject OAuth[22187:11603] I
>   restkit.network:RKRequest.m:689 Status Code: 401

I realized that Restkit would not add any parameters in this way and hence the request is not aware of what signature, timestamp and OAuth version to use. Hence I tried the same using POST request where I can specify these parameters. Even now I get an empty body and the Restkit log says this:

> 2012-11-06 19:28:03.231 MyProject OAuth[22205:11603] I
>   restkit.network:RKRequest.m:689 Status Code: 404

I do not know where I am going wrong or what else to try! Looking forward for help in resolving this issue.

**EDIT:**
I implemented a missing callback method and now am getting:

> "The request must be signed"

message. I presume that the above setup should have been enough for OAuth authentication, as mentioned in the referred link, what else am I supposed to do?

***Observations***:

I could see the internals of RestKit code and the OAuth parameters are put into the HTTP header field of the URL request. But am not sure if Drupal 7 is capable of reading this information from the HTTP header field for it always returns me back:

> The request must be signed

Which means that the OAuth parameters are not received by Drupal in first case, otherwise it would have given me the following error at least:

> Invalid Signature

I was looking for some other options to see if my consumer key and secret and all the other setup is done properly in the server side or not. To confirm this I downloaded the php OAuth client script from [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/). Download the SVN code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/checkout). In that when I cross check the requests with PHP client, my requests are all being served perfectly & I get back the xml by just entering the endpoint, consumer key and consumer secret.

One more thing I tried is to allow GCOAuth to generate the signature and all inside the Restkit and placed a breakpoint so that I can dump the HTTP header fields in a log and instead of Restkit sending the request to the server, I quickly prepared the URL request exactly in the same format as the above PHP client does. Now this request when triggered, I get back the

> Invalid Signature

response, does this also somehow mean that the OAuth parameters are not properly prepared in Restkit / GCOAuth?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by making changes in the Restkit's classes. As per my observations mentioned in the question above, I was able to figure out what I assume is a limitation of some of the webservers, lets say Drupal 7 in this case. Almost in all of the OAuth libraries I have come across for iOS, the OAuth authentication parameters were set in the HTTP header fields of the request.

I came across the [PHP client](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) (as mentioned in my observations above) where if we provide proper consumer key and consumer secret, it will generate the oauth_nonce string, the timestamp and will also provide the oauth_signature inside the URL's query parameters. This capability was missing in Restkit's libraries (I assume?). Though Restkit fills in the HTTP header field with all the information provided by GCOAuth, I feel that my Drupal 7 webserver was not reading it somehow, or maybe I was using the wrong key for the HTTP header field. I searched for the documentation of Drupal 7 on how to pass the parameters in HTTP header field and read it from there, but I could not find much help and am not that proficient at it though.

So my solution was to build the URL request just as the way the mentioned [PHP client](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) does. Almost everything was done by Restkit within the GCOAuth class, RKClient & RKRequest classes. All I had to do was to tweak so that the OAuth parameters are appended to the request URL. All my changes I have pushed to a [forked code of Restkit in github](https://github.com/gumdal/RestKit). My changes specific to this OAuth module are commented with **"// Raj OAuth:"** which can be searched in the project.

Below is the code which I have successfully used to trigger and consume the webservice. For now I have provided an overloaded designated method for RKClient's `-get:delegate:` method, the same can be extended to all other available methods on need basis, I believe.

```
-(void)triggerOAuthRequest
{
    NSString *urlResource = @"";
    urlResource = @"/endpoint_path/endpoint.xml";
    NSString *baseURL = @"http://your_domain_name.com/path_to_drupal_home_folder/";
    NSString *consumerKey = @"YW9h6tUc*************";
    NSString *consumerSecret = @"HUS2ALAC*************";

    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:baseURL];
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
    objectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
    objectManager.client.OAuth1ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
    objectManager.client.OAuth1AccessToken = nil;
    objectManager.client.OAuth1AccessTokenSecret = nil;
    objectManager.client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeOAuth1;
    [objectManager.client get:urlResource
                     delegate:self
constructOAuthQueryParamsInURL:YES];
}
```

I also assume that sending this request is safe enough for the fact that my OAuth parameters are signed with the secret consumer key at the client end and after that the request is sent to the server, though the URL itself has the query parameters, I feel it is safe coz the oauth_signature is signed with secret consumer key which only the webserver can decrypt and check if the request is from authentic sources.

If you feel there is scope for any improvement please let me know.

Thanks,

Raj